# Define an activity as widget with title

Tags: android, widget, icons, title

Just want to know how to create an widget (even if I personally doesn't consider that like a widget) from an activity.

My goal is to build a quick add widget that looks like a standard app icon : same size, and with a title.

On this screen, you can see app (from app tab) at the left and widget (from widget tab) at the right :

[image: On this screen, you can see app (from app tab) at the left and widget (from widget tab) at the right]

Any informations about that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to create a shortcut on the desktop:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
Log.i("CreateShortcut", "Creating first intent called shortcutIntent");
shortcutIntent.setClassName(getPackageName(), "CreateShortcut");
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Intent intent = new Intent();
Log.i("CreateShortcut", "Creating intent for broadcasting");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ShortcutName");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, false);
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```